# Investment calculator refuses to calculate properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program runs but definitely not how it's meant to. No matter which input I put it, it always says "You've earned: $0.00" and I'm tried moving "months_invested = years_investment / 12" to multiple places and even adding or taking away bits.

The investment calculator is meant to compound this stuff monthly but I cannot seem to get it right. One problem turns to two and it's like the hydra to me, where you fix one thing and it multiplies itself.

```
"""

 InvestmentCalculator.py helps generate how much interest one earns after a certain period of time
 """


 def main():
     total_money = 0
     months_invested = 0
     years_investment = 0

 investment = float(input("How much would you like to invest? "))
 years_investment = float(input("How many years would you like to invest? "))
 interest_rate = float(input("What is the interest rate? "))
 total_money = float()
 months_invested = float()


 while months_invested > 0:
     months_invested = (years_investment / 12) - 1
     total_money = investment +  total_money
     print("You have earned ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))
 else: print("You've earned a total of ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))


 main()
```

Comment: `months_invested` starts *not* greater than 0, so your code never enters the while loop.

Comment: Did you mean to do `months_invested = years_investment / 12`?

Comment: You do not need to declare variables in python, so ` months_invested = float()
` isn't should just be the calculation you already did inside the loop, but put before/outside the loop. Additionally, is the code all supposed to be in the `main` function? Because the indentation in your code is very confusing as written

Comment: You are also not using `interest_rate` in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple things going here.

1. The while loop will be entered when the condition is met, and it seems that never changes from just a `float()` before hitting the while loop.
2. The indentation is off and everything after `years_investment = 0` is not in the `main()` function. (this is probably just a copy/paste issue when posting the question.)
3. When if you were to get into the for loop, you would end up being stick in it because your are not actually decrementing the `months_investment` value.

I did some refactoring to get you where I think you want to be.

```
def main():
    investment = float(input("How much would you like to invest? "))
    months_investment = float(int(input("How many years would you like to invest? ")) * 12)
    interest_rate = float(input("What is the interest rate? "))
    total_money = 0

    while months_investment > 0:
        total_money += investment * interest_rate
        print("You have earned ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))
        months_investment -= 1
    else: print("You've earned a total of ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))


main()
```

Comment: I'd also like to say thank you. For some reason I never thought that you could put an  `else` statement on a while loop. So that's a new one for the toolbox.

Comment: Be careful if I use `interest_rate = 1` which is a valid interest rate, I am getting no interests, because of the formula used. Furthermore you are summing the investment in a monthly basis which is not the basis for compound interest, but for fixed deposit instruments.

Comment: @halfer I was a bit harsh with the comment at first, that's why I was editing it. I apologize for that.

Comment: No worries @Celius. I wasn't worried about whether it was rude, though I agree it is good to be mindful of such things. I just thought that most people like actionable advice, and "it's wrong" will prompt a response to ask what specifically is wrong. So you might as well add that in the first comment if you can `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this is what you are trying to achieve. There were some adjustments to be made which I'll explain below the code:

```
def main():    
    total_money = float(input("How much would you like to invest? "))
    years_investment = float(input("How many years would you like to invest? "))
    interest_rate = float(input("What is the monthly interest rate in %? "))

    months_invested = years_investment * 12
    while months_invested > 0:
        interests = interest_rate / 100 * total_money
        total_money += interests
        print("You have earned ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))
        months_invested += -1

main()
```

Output:

```
You have earned $101.00
You have earned $102.01
You have earned $103.03
You have earned $104.06
You have earned $105.10
You have earned $106.15
You have earned $107.21
You have earned $108.29
You have earned $109.37
You have earned $110.46
You have earned $111.57
You have earned $112.68
```

As G.Anderson stated, there's no need to initialize variables with value 0 (or any value). Simply define it as the input.

The months investment formula was wrong and troubled the loop. Also, if that was fixed, the loop would run infinitely since there was no limit or condition that would end it (that's what the `months_invested += -1` is for. To decrease the value of the variable each time the loop passes so it stops sometime (that is, when there are no more investments months).

Finally remember your function is printing a result and not returning anything so be careful when using it in advance.

If you needed compound interest (monthly) then you should use the formula for compound interest. That is `(((1+i) ** months) -1) * $`. In this case I'm using `total_money += interests` to sum the interests generated in the period to the total amount of money, which will be reinvested in the following period (hence, compound interest).

There is no real need to use a while loop, other approaches might be more efficient, using lists or arrays for instance. However I respected the original structure of your code for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`months_invested` is set by the line `months_invested = float()`, where it is initialized to zero. This means that the while loop never runs. You want `months_invested = years_investment * 12`.

It's worth noting that this still won't do what you want, but I don't want to provide you with an entire answer: struggling with problems is an important part of learning.